# Is there any easy way to simplify an expression like this? $(-x^2-x-1)(x-1)(-e^{-x})+(-x^2-x-1)(-2(x-1)^{-3})(e^{-x})+(-2x-1)(x-1)^{-2}(e^{-x})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any easy way to simplify an expression like this?

$(-x^2-x-1)(x-1)(-e^{-x})+(-x^2-x-1)(-2(x-1)^{-3})(e^{-x})+(-2x-1)(x-1)^{-2}(e^{-x})$

I know that factor the common terms is used for expressions like
$5*(x^{2}+x)+5*(x^2+x)$ but I find tricky to understand when it can be applied in cases with many products inside each of the sum terms.
Can you help me to understand what I can do here? I tried to solve by FOIL method, but it seems to me that I'm doing too much work for it.

Comment: By doing some nice tricks we get: $e^{-x}(x^3 + 3 (x + 1)/(x - 1)^3 - 1)$.

Comment: Clearly, you can take $e^{-x}$ outside. I feel, the identity $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ might also come in handy.

Comment: *Mathemtica*:  $$\frac{e^{-x} \left(x^6-3 x^5+3 x^4-2 x^3+3 x^2+4\right)}{(x-1)^3}$$